# Merge CSVs, match columns with different formats

Tags: csv, powershell

I have two CSVs, first one is formatted like this:

```
Campus ID,Student ID,Grade,Last Name,First Name,Active
1,50000,12,TEST,USER,1
1,600000,12,EXAMPLE,USER,1
```

I then need to merge another CSV:

```
Name,E-Mail Address
User Test,30TestU@example.com
User Example,40ExampleU@example.com
```

I need to merge or create a new CSV, matching the first and last name column in the first CSV to the name column in the second, and then add another column with the matched user's email address. I don't need to retain the names from the second CSV.

For example, the result would look like this:

```
Campus ID,Student ID,Grade,Last Name,First Name,Active,Email
1,50000,12,TEST,USER,1,30TestU@example.com
1,600000,12,EXAMPLE,USER,1,40ExampleU@example.com
```

I've tried this with PowerShell, and was able to get the extra column, but matching the names since they are in different formats was a bit too much. I'm not requiring PowerShell for this, I can use something else if it works better.

Comment: If this is a one time process, I would use Excel.  Open file 1 in Worksheet 1 and create a Name field that the second file can key to, open file 2 in Worksheet 2, and build your combined file in whichever sheet has more records.  Use sort and VLOOKUP.  Then go back and manually deal with all the students with duplicate names.  If you need this to be an automated  process then you're screwed. Names are nowhere unique enough to be useful as a key.

Comment: To follow up on @BaconBits comment ... he's right about repeated processes. If it's _not_ a one time process you have a real problem, because you'll never get good matches based on name. There are just too many cases of duplicate names, nick-names, spelling variations, etc. I'll do one-off matches on names, but I refuse work that requires me to join data sources on names of people and send those requests back to the drawing board.

Comment: This is a one-time deal. I can deal with duplicates, there are not very many students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution though I would never use this as it would simply pick the first match if multiple users have the same name. And a single change (error or maybe a middle name) would break it.

```
<# Sample One
$one = @"
Campus ID,Student ID,Grade,Last Name,First Name,Active
1,50000,12,TEST,USER,1
1,600000,12,EXAMPLE,USER,1
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
#>

$one = Import-Csv SampleOne.csv

<# Sample two
$two = @"
Name,E-Mail Address
User Test,30TestU@example.com
User Example,40ExampleU@example.com
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
#>

$two = Import-Csv SampleTwo.csv

$three = $one | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_."First Name" + " " + $_."Last Name"
    $email = $two | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $name } | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty "E-Mail Address"
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Email -Value $email -PassThru
}

$three |
Select-Object "Campus ID","Student ID","Grade","Last Name","First Name","Active","Email" |
Export-Csv -Path Out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"Campus ID","Student ID","Grade","Last Name","First Name","Active","Email"
"1","50000","12","TEST","USER","1","30TestU@example.com"
"1","600000","12","EXAMPLE","USER","1","40ExampleU@example.com"
```

Comment: I used this, it worked very well. Only a few that it couldn't match, but manually matching them wasn't a problem. Thank you.